# Zabbix cuts value of the custom item while displaying it in trigger

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I've got an issue with setting up triggers, which displays value of the custom item (string). I can't figure why and how Zabbix cuts off value:

*Host isn't avail...*

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is about the [last] value macrovariable, that would cut at 20 characters, as per https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1016 .

While there is no way to nicely configure the limit, the frontend files can be hacked to change it.